# How to serialise both positional and non-positional arguments of Python objects?

Tags: python, serialization

How can I serialise `test` below:

```
class Foo:
    a = 0
    b = {}

    def __init__(self, a, b=None):
        self.a = a

        if b:
            self.b = b


test = Foo(1)
test.b['c'] = 2
```

so that the output is:

```
{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2}}
```

I've tried:

```
print(json.dumps(test, default=lambda x: x.__dict__))
```

but it returns:

```
{"a": 1}
```

I understand that `test.b['c'] = 2` does not add `b` or `c` to `Foo.__dict__`, which is probably why `x.__dict__` in the lambda doesn't pick them up. So is the answer one of:

1. Do not assign key-value pairs to arbitrary objects; use `setattr` instead.
2. Do not define arbitrary classes, if its property set can evolve at runtime; use a simple `dict` instead.

Comment: test is an object of class foo. Unless you're going out of the way to build a rigorous serializer and deserializer for your class, it's better to stick to serialization using tools intended to handle objects. simple json dumps is not meant for this purpose. If your end goal is to recover the object in python, take a look at pickle.

Comment: thanks. perhaps i went too far with calling it 'serialisation'... all i really need (at this stage) is compare 2 dicts for unit tests: i manually write the expected dict in the test, and the actual dict would be the 'serialised' (better word?) version of the Foo instance.

Comment: "I understand that test.b['c'] = 2 does not add b or c to Foo.__dict__, which is probably why x.__dict__ in the lambda doesn't pick them up." That is incorrect. It is *precisely because* `test.b['c'] = 2` adds to `Foo.__dict__` that it isn't showing up when the lambda works *on the instance instead*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `test.b` is not a instance variable. So when you serialize the object `test` using `json.dumps`, its not finding an instance variable `b` at all.

If you redefine the constructor like below:

```
class Foo:
    a = 0 #this is not instance variable - this is a class variable
    b = {} #this is not instance variable - this is a class variable

    def __init__(self, a, b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = {} #declared the instance variable b also
        if b:
            self.b = b


test = Foo(1)
test.b['c'] = 2
```

Now, if you run you get the desired output.

Comment: this solved it! tanks. i'll approve this is the right answer but... I now realise (through your answer) that the question does not reflect my problem 100%... so if you can/want, here's the updated question: what if `b` is nowhere mentioned in the class definition, not as class var or instance var, but i still want to dynamically add it to `test` at runtime. How can I a) add it (I think test['b'] would spit an error) and b) convert test to `dict`?

Comment: @Rodrigo It's not very clear to me what you mean here.  You can dynamically add instance or class attributes like normal at any time, so I'm not sure what the problem is exactly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga do you mean I can do `setattr(test, 'b', {"c": 2})`?

Comment: @Rodrigo well sure, but you can just do `test.b = {'c': 2}` I'm not sure why you are mentioning `setattr`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga even if `b` is not defined as class or instance var?

Comment: @Rodrigo what do you mean? That *is* defining it as an instance variable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga very true. thanks! i'll revise my code and see why my dynamically defined instance variables are not appearing in the `dict` I'm trying to match in my unit tests. I think the above answers all my questions for now. Thanks all!